# Mocking navigator in RN for unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, mocha.js, sinon

For my tests, Am using `mocha`, `enzyme`, `sinon` for stubing and `chai` for assertions, `mockery` for mocking modules.

Now whats the best possible mechanism to mock navigator for geolocation. I tried `rewire` from `https://github.com/jhnns/rewire` to inject my sinon stubed navigator. This will work for me, but just feels cumbersome to setup the stub.
I like https://github.com/2gis/mock-geolocation as it feels more natural way of mocking. But unfortunately am not able to use it because it uses `window` variable.

I tried to use `mocha-jsdom` like

```
import jsdom from 'mocha-jsdom';
jsdom();
const geolocate = require('mock-geolocation');
```

But I get an error like

```
/..../node_modules/mock-geolocation/src/geolocate.js:225
})(window, navigator);
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/like

/..../node_modules/mock-geolocation/src/geolocate.js:225:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

I run my tests like this `mocha --require react-native-mock/mock --compilers js:babel-register --recursive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `mocha-jsdom`, I used `this.jsdom = require('jsdom-global')()`
That seemed to fix it.